# restrict mongodb document growth beyond 8MB

Tags: mongodb, database

Problem statement:

We have a requirement to restrict document growth beyond 8MB .(Let say in this 8MB we accomodate 7000 small log entires )
once the document reaches 8MB, further insertion should be done on second document with the same above said constraint(s) 
and if  on first document, few log entries are removed then will document size shrik autmatically as we dealt with "pre-allocation strategy"

I refered few links from mongodb as below :: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-operations/#data-model-document-growth

Above link states that there is a "pre-allocation strategy to explicitly avoid document growth"

Our queries::

1. Can we impose such a constraint (say 8MB limit on collections )
2. if (1) is possible please aid us in achieving this requirement

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, no, there's not a straightforward way to enforce such a limit on the database side. If you wanted to enforce such a limit, you'd need to handle this within your client application.

Second, the link that you provided and the notion of pre-allocation really only applies to the MMAPv1 storage engine. In most cases, you probably want to use WiredTiger instead.

Lastly, make sure that you understand the implications of creating such large documents. Even 8MB is *very* large. Think about how you want to read/query your data before you settle on a model for how you store it. If your access pattern is to read a small number of log entries, then reading them in such large batches is going to be very inefficient.